# Как в Winforms запретить нажатие одной кнопки до нажатия другой?

Tags: c#, winforms

Господа, изучая С#, не осознаю, как реализовать такую задачу. У меня есть форма с двумя кнопками. Пусть нажатие на `button1` определяет N = 2, а на `button2` определяет N = 10.

**Вопрос:** как запретить пользователю нажимать на кнопку `button2`, пока хотя бы один раз не нажата кнопка `button1?`

Вообще, задумка такая.

Программа запускается: пользователю доступна для нажатия только `button1`. Нажать на `button2` изначально нельзя, потому что она "вдавлена". Пользователю ничего не остается, кроме как нажать на `button1`. После нажатия на `button1`, "вдавливается" `button1`, а `button2` "оживает", и нажать на нее уже можно.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public
            int N;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            N = 2;
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            N = 10;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала определимся с тем, что такое "пока не нажата первая кнопка". Достаточно нажать на первую один раз - и потом сколько угодно раз жми вторую? (или после каждого нажатия второй надо заново нажимать первую?) Или первая кнопка "втапливается" и пока её не нажмёшь второй раз она так и остаётся в этом "нажатом" положении?

Comment: @AK, спасибо, уточнила

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button.Enabled` управляет активностью кнопки, такое же свойство есть и у других контролов.

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button2.Enabled = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = true;
    N = 2;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button1.Enabled = true;
    N = 10;
}
```

Таким образом для нажатия будет доступна только одна из 2 кнопок. Но если вам нужно больше кнопок, я не рекомендую использовать этот метод выбора значения для переменной, лучше использовать `RadioButton` ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=netframework-4.8)).

Comment: спасибо большое! Я ещё почему-то была уверена, что каждая кнопка будет "видна" только в "своём" блоке. А это оказалось не так

Comment: @Helga_Pataki в своем блоке видна кнопка, обработчик которой выполняется, и получить эту кнопку можно так `Button currentButton = (Button)sender;`, этот фокус очень полезен, например если вы хотите использовать один и тот же обработчик для нескольких кнопок. Все остальные контролы доступны по именам.